# Fixed width text file to python dictionary

Tags: python, text, io

I am trying to import in Python a text file similar to the one reported below.

```
+ CATEGORY_1 first_part of long attribute <NAME_a>
|     ...second part of long attribute
|    + CATEGORY_2: a sequence of attributes that extend over 
|    |     ... possibly many <NAME_b>
|    |     ... lines
|    |    + SOURCE_1 => source_code 
|    + CATEGORY_2: another sequence of attributes that extend over <NAME_c>
|    |     ... possibly many lines
|    |    + CATEGORY_1: yet another sequence of <NAME_d> attributes that extend over
|    |    |     ...many lines 
|    |    |    + CATEGORY_2: I really think <NAME_e> that
|    |    |    |     ... you got the point 
|    |    |    |     ... now
|    |    |    |    + SOURCE_1 => source_code 
|    + SOURCE_2 => path_to_file
```

Where assume that i can easily identify the name of the object as delimited by <...>

My ideal output would be a Python dictionary which reflects the hierarchy of the txt file, so for example:

```
{NAME_a : {'category' : CATEGORY_1,
           'depencencies' : {NAME_b : {'category' : CATEGORY_2,
                                       'source_type' : SOURCE_1,
                                       'source_code' : source_code}
                             NAME_c : {'category' : CATEGORY_2,
                                       'dependencies' : { NAME_d : {'category' : CATEGORY_1,
                                                                    'dependencies' : NAME_e : {'category' : CATEGORY_2,
                                                                                               'source_type' : SOURCE_1,
                                                                                               'source_code' : source_code}
                                                                    }
                                                        }           
            'source_type' : SOURCE_2,
            'source_code : path_to_file
           }
}
```

In think the main idea here is to count the number of tabs before line begins and this will dictate the hierarchy.
I have tried to look at pandas read_fwf and numpy loadfromtxt, but without any success.
Can you point me to relevant modules or strategies to solve this problem?

Comment: Any hint on how to approach the problem would be appreciated. Not looking only for "out of the box" solutions.

Comment: Strategy: since your data structure is flat (it's a text file), you need to develop your own parser to guess to level, recognize the name… To build the dictionary structure you'll need a stack.

Answer (score 0):

Not a complete answer but you can follow an approach using a stack.

Every time you enter a category you push the category key to the stack.
Then you read the line, check the number of tabs and store according. If the level is the same or higher than the precedent you pop an item from the stack.
Then you just need basic regex to extract the items.

Some Python/pseudocode so you can have an idea

```
levels = []
items = {}
last_level = 0

for line in file:
   current_level = count_tabs()
   if current_level > last_level:
      name = extract_name(line)
      levels.append(name)
      items = fill_dictionary_in_level(name, line)
   else:
      levels.pop()
   last_level = current_level

return items
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a strategy:

For each line, use RegEx to parse the line and extract data.

Here is a draft:

```
import re

line = "|    + CATEGORY_2: another sequence of attributes that extend over <NAME_c>"

level = line.count("|") + 1
mo = re.match(r".*\+\s+(?P<category>[^:]+):.*<(?P<name>[^>]+)>", line)
category = mo.group("category")
name = mo.group("name")

print("level: {0}".format(level))
print("category: {0}".format(category))
print("name: {0}".format(name))
```

You get:

```
level: 2
category: CATEGORY_2
name: NAME_c
```